# Error while enrolling: empty access_token

Tags: kibana, filebeat

I have successfully installed a full ELK Docker stack including Filebeat.
When I want to enroll a Filebeat instance, I get the following error:

```
Error while enrolling: empty access_token
```

According to [the source](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/x-pack/libbeat/management/api/enroll.go), the error can be anything, if the response is not nice.

`filebeat.yml`:

```
filebeat.config:
    modules:
        path: /usr/share/filebeat/config/modules.d/*.yml
        reload.enabled: false

filebeat.modules:
    -   module: apache2

processors:
    -   add_cloud_metadata: ~

output.elasticsearch:
    hosts: 'http://elasticsearch:9200'
    username: 'elastic'
    password: 'changeme'

setup.kibana:
    host: "http://kibana:5601/"
    username: "elastic"
    password: "changeme"

name: "apache-test"
```

What is wrong?